# Perl variable subroutine name

Tags: perl, subroutine

Want to call a function in a variable subroutine name, like that :

```
use subrest1;
use subrest2;
use subrest3;
$SUB = "subrest1";
```

Tried :

```
($OK,$MSG) = \&$SUB::Test_Ldev($LDEVID);
```

Returns me the following message :

`Undefined subroutine &main:: called`

Where is my error ?

Comment: What is the actual value of the variable? What sub are you trying to call?

Comment: $SUB = "subrest1";

Comment: Are you trying to do the equivalent of calling subrest1($LDEVID) or subrest1::Test_Ldev($LDEVID), or what?

Comment: I want to call subrest1::Test_Ldev($LDEVID) or subrest2::Test_Ldev($LDEVID) depending on the value contained in $SUB which can be subrest1 or subrest2 (or subrestn) in the program

Answer (score 4):

The cleanest solution is to convert the various `Test_Ldev` subs into class methods. This is done by allowing for an extra argument.

```perl
sub Test_Ldev { 
   my ( $class, $LDEVID ) = @_;
   ...
}
```

Then the call becomes the following:

```perl
my ( $OK, $MSG ) = $SUB->Test_Ldev( $LDEVID );
```

Comment: Made the change for this sub in my subrest1 but when calling, got this error : Can't locate object method "Test_Ldev" via package "subrest1" (perhaps you forgot to load "subrest1"?), The perl module subrest1 is loaded (used successfully by another sub in another part of my main program)

Comment: Sounds like you didn't use the right `package` statement in `subrest1.pm`. It should be `package subrest1;`. The file name, `use` statement and `package` statement must* match.

Comment: Works fine with ```($OK,$MSG) = (\&{$SUB."::Test_Ldev"})->($LDEVID);``` and does not need to modify all the functions in the package

Comment: I'm aware of that since I'm the one who told you that solution. But it's a pretty terrible solution compared to the one presented in this answer.